# What's the most appropriate way to sizeof a struct

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I've seen 3 different ways to sizeof a struct in C.

```
typedef struct A {
    int a, b;
} A;


sizeof(A); // method 1

sizeof(struct A); // method 2

A *p; 
sizeof(*p); // method 3
```

Which one is the most appropriate way to do this? Consider the efficiency and readability.

Comment: Method 2 is a lot slower than method 1, but method 3 takes a lot more memory. I think method 1 is O(N^2).

Comment: These are all computed at compile time.  What do you mean by "efficiency"?

Comment: sizeof is compile time so its optimized away anyhow in all the 3 cases

Comment: So you explained me the efficiency is the same. Thanks! But I'm still confused with which one is more readable. @WilliamPursell

Comment: Method 1 might have its place, so does method 3. However method 2 makes me wonder why to typedef in the first place. It's not consistent and I like consistency. (Method 3 gives you the advantage of being able to change the type of `p` without risking nasty bugs).

Comment: @KerrekSB What? Can you back those statements up with something?

Comment: I've seen method 1 and method 3 in codes of same project. I found method 2 when I tried to google similar questions. So I think you are right that method 2 should not appear after a typedef. @Jite

Comment: Method 3 is to be preferred, but you don't need (and *should not use*) the parentheses. Just `sizeof *p` will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except when using variable-length arrays, `sizeof` is 100% compile-time. So there is no "efficiency", except indirectly with regard to readability, understandability, safety, and so on.

I favor the version with the least repetition, and also with the least typing. Thus, if a pointer is available I always use the third form, but *without the parenthesis* since they're not needed.

For instance:

```
float *a = malloc(1000 * sizeof *a);
```

Note that code like this "locks" the `sizeof` to the pointer being used, which is at least slighly better (I'd argue it's a lot better, since typical functions have less pointers in scope than they have type names) than repeating the type since the risk of mis-matching decreases accordingly.

The parenthesis in code like `sizeof(float)` or your `sizeof(A)` are only needed when the argument is a type name. Since it makes it look like a function call, which it is not, when I have to use that form I always format it with a space:

```
void *p = malloc(1000 * sizeof (float));
```

Remember that *`sizeof` is not a function*.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct, the parenthesis is part of `sizeof`. C11 6.5.3.4/2 `The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.`. See also the syntax in 6.5.3: `sizeof unary-expression`, `sizeof ( type-name )`.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf for the definition of `sizeof (T)` in section 6.5.3. `sizeof (T)` is not a cast `(T)` but "normal" brackets. Furthermore I would prefer `sizeof(*a)` since changing `a`'s type is automatically reflected by this expression.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, I hadn't actually read that, I got my understanding of `sizeof` elsewhere. I edited to remove the reference to a cast.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time(*) so they are all equally efficient.

The rest of your question is about coding style.

There are two camps debating whether or not to use typedef for structs. One camp (most notably the Linux kernel people) thinks that `struct A` is clearer than the `typedef`. The other camp (pretty much everyone except the Linux people) thinks that `typedef` is clearer. These are subjective opinions and there is no consensus, no right or wrong. Either form is fine.

And then there is another coding style debate about whether `sizeof(type_of_ptr)` or `sizeof(*ptr)` is clearer. Again, there is no consensus, this is subjective coding style.

Thus the answer to your question is: it depends on your coding style standard. One which ever form that your coding standard dictates for your current project.

---

(*) Except sizeof VLAs

Comment: The difference between `sizeof object` and `sizeof(type)` is not merely subjective. Consider the statements `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` and `p = malloc(sizeof(type));`. In the absence of some horrible preprocessor macro for `p`, the former can be objectively determined to allocate the correct size for `*p`, but the latter requires more information before a determination can be made. There is therefore an objective, not subjective, difference between the two forms.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have no preference and I don't want to debate it. But the equally "objective" counter-argument is that if `p` is a pointer-to-pointer, for example a parameter passed to a function to get malloc:ed, then it is very easy to slip and write the wrong level of indirection. Because it is not obvious whether to use `**p` or `*p` or `p`. While `**p` would be correct for my malloc-inside-function example, it would be incorrect if malloc was called from main(). And this could also be confusing when dealing with static multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: How is that relevant? Neither `p = malloc(sizeof *p);` nor `p = malloc(sizeof(type));` aids with detecting whether the correct level of indirection has been applied to `p`. E.g., if `*p = malloc(sizeof **p);` or `*p = malloc(sizeof(type));` should have been used, neither form is more helpful in determining that.

Comment: @Lundin That's another story though. `sizeof *p` allows you to change type of `p` and it will still give you correct size, while `sizeof type` wont follow `p`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I personally think the whole debate between those styles is bloated beyond reason. I have programmed C for some 15 years and I have never encountered the problem "I want to malloc something but I don't know what". In the real world when you are typing that malloc line, you know what you are trying to malloc. I can't even remember ever making a bug with the incorrect amount of bytes malloc'd because of incorrect type. Seems like a non-issue to me.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, I might have similar thoughts when I had only 15 years of experience. However, the problem is not “I want to write a malloc now, and finding the type of *p is hard.” The problem is that `p` is declared with `FancyTypePointer p`, and `FancyTypePointer` is defined in some header file included in some other header file included when a certain compiler switch is defined, and it is defined as a pointer to `FancyType` which is defined by a preprocessor macro in some obscure header, and somebody changes the macro and tries to find everywhere it is used but misses one etc.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That problem is called "maintaining obscure pre-processor macros" and not unique to the sizeof issue. Instead of changing your coding style to dodge obscure macros, don't write them in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin: (a) It is not just about macros. There are various ways in which chains of types get defined. Code gets complex. (b) One does not always have a choice about obscure macros. They get declared in headers that come from some other portion of the project or some other project, and the headers have to support diverse targets and need preprocessor features to adapt to those targets. Code gets complex. Saying we ought to avoid doing things that breaks code does not eliminate the benefits of writing code to resist breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The typedef here is pointless, and obfuscates the fact that you missed an important use of sizeof. I'll pretend you did not use a typedef and instead are asking about taking the size of a variable.  Eg, you have a variable named `A` of type `struct A`.

In terms of readability, it all depends on context (and personal preference).  When allocating memory, it is more readable to use 3:

```
p = malloc( sizeof *p );
```

When attempting to determine the size of the struct, it is better to use 2 (although this is a very contrived example, as method 2 is almost never desirable):

```
char *ptr;  /* eventually points to an array of struct A */
ptr += sizeof( struct A );
```

If you want to know the size of a variable, use method 1:

```
void *ptr = malloc( COUNT * sizeof A );
```

In practice, method 3 is almost always preferred.  (This is a statement of personal opinion.)

I short, determine why you are computing the size.  That will drive the definition of "readable".

Answer (score 0):

When comes to use of sizeof operator to evaluate the size of statically declared arrays you may do this in one fancy way - `sizeof(some_type[some_size])`.

So, lets say you have some custom defined type:

```
struct some_struct {
        int some_int;
};
```

Then, in the least simple compilable primer you can use something like this:

```
#define PREFERABLE_SIZE 1000

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[static const 1])
{
        return sizeof(struct some_struct[PREFERABLE_SIZE]);
        /* Or you may do this with some base type (i.e, float) */
        /* return sizeof(float[PREFERABLE_SIZE]); */
}
```

`sizeof(some_type[some_size])` is equivalent to `some_size * sizeof(some_type)`. As for me, the former is much preferable and "prettier" than the latter.